# Placing text over svg image

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am using a git repository to display a chessboard:

https://github.com/shaack/cm-chessboard

An example of the displayed chessboard can be found here:

https://shaack.com/projekte/cm-chessboard/

My goal is to display some text over a square of my choice, which would display over the piece if it is present. So I presume that involves some kind of z-index on the svg.

I've done inspect on the chessboard to see what the source code looks like, but I am at a loss for how to add a function that works like this:

`function(coordinate,text)`, where coordinate could be something like c2.

How would you go about creating this function?

I am at a loss of where to start. I've been looking at the source code in the git file and commenting the code to get a better understanding. Ideally I would like a function that doesn't alter the git repository, because then if they do an update, my code won't break. Maybe I need to add a function that modifies the instance of the board object.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to your repos aren't adequate. You should be able to reduce the problem to a small HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I did a modern Chessboard (only to show the power of Web Components)

Problem with the "traditional" approach is you can NOT ***extend*** on it;
without taking the source code and changing it.

Modern Web Components **can** be **extended** *WITHOUT* needing the source code.

Below is ALL code required to add the `label( square , label )` functionality you are after.

Better yet, same code in: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/jvpm875b/

One issue.. the square-label is still shown; because my CSS was created to hide the square-label when there is a Chess-Piece in the square. You have to dig into the CSS to change that.

ChessMeister  was an experiment, meant to be a BaseClass for Web Component developers; it has the UNlicense on it.. so you are free to use it (and you can't sue me)

https://chessmeister.github.io/

```html
<script src="https://chessmeister.github.io/elements.chessmeister.js"></script>
<script>
  customElements.define( "chess-board", 
  class extends customElements.get("chessmeister-board") {
    connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback(); // execute <chessmeister-board>
      let style = document.createElement("style");
      style.innerHTML = `#labels div{background:rgb(100,100,0,.5);font:16px Arial;color:red;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center}`
      this.shadowRoot.append(style);
      this.labels = this.addlayer("labels");
      this.label("A7", "Make");
      this.label("B7", "Your");
      this.label("C7", "Own");
      this.label("D7", "Chess");
      this.label("E7", "Board");
    }
    label(square = "A8", label = "LABEL") {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute("at", square);
      div.innerHTML = label;
      this.labels.append(div);
      return div;
    }
  })
</script>
<chess-board fen="4r3/8/2p2PPk/1p6/pP2p1R1/P1B5/2P2K2/3r4"></chess-board>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Danny. I am not looking to switch from my existing chessboard git repository, but maybe I can learn something from what you have said. I am not sure what you mean when you say Modern Web Components. What do they do that makes it modern? I've been wondering if I can `extend` the git repository I am currently using, by adding a method to the instance.

Comment: That git repo is source-code. You have to change it, rebuilt it, to get something new.. its the (classic) software development life-cycle we have done since the 1950s. Web Components are OOP. You use an existing object as BaseClass and you extend it (inheritance) **without touching the original source**.

Comment: What I meant by extend the git repository is extend the classes used in that source code. If I could add a labelling function by extending say the chessboard class in that source code, that would be ideal. Are you saying that would not be possible because the git source code is old school, or did I misunderstand you there?

Comment: Not oldskool.. just how most of us program... take source code, change it, create a new version. You have to **fork and rebuilt** all that git code. With good OOP Web Components its the IKEA approach.. you get what you like, give it a paint and you are done. Alas most software development (read: all the Frameworks) is still in the _**rebuilt EVERYTHING after making a change**_ phase. Like wanting a sun-roof and having to rebuilt your whole house.

Comment: Hi, I am the creator of cm-chessboard. It is coded in ES6, so you can extend classes, like `class ExtendedChessboard extends Chessboard { /* overwirte methods here */ }` for more help you can contact me with the email address in https://shaack.com.